# How to save a custom field value in DB for add new customers in backend magento2.2.5?

Tags: magento2

I have created a module for adding a new field **Store Number** in Add new customers in magento backend.
But not able to save the field value in database.

Refer my screenshot.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you created this custom attribute as EAV Attribute ?
Can you find its values in eav_attribute Table?

Comment: Can you share your code which you have tried?